# Why 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts' error?

Tags: trigger, deployment, webservices, error, callout

I have simple trigger that changes value of one field based on value of other field.

Following is test class for that Trigger

```
@isTest
public class SMS_OPT_OUT_TC{
    static testmethod void triggerTest(){
            Account a = NEW Account();
            a.FirstName='John';
            a.LastName='DoeTest1';
            a.PersonEmail = 'doetest1@test.com';
            a.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = True;
            insert a;
            Account b = new Account();
            b.FirstName = 'John';
            b.LastName = 'DoeTest2';
            b.PersonEmail = 'doetest2@test.com';
            b.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = True;
            insert b;            
            a.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = True;
            update a;
            b.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = True;
            update b;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts' error when I try to deploy it.

I searched other similar questions and all seems to advising using Mock Response for webservice Callouts but I don't have any callouts in my Testclass.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are some callouts in triggers on account

Comment: kurunve has it spot on (could also be in triggers and their handler classes of sobjects updated by flows/workflows executed when accounts are inserted/updated)

Comment: Thanks for the hint guys. I actually still can't find use of callout anywhere. Can this be caused by managed class by any apps?